# Can't assign instance of a Swift class conforming to a protocol to an Objective-C property expecting that protocol

Tags: swift, objective-c, uikit, protocols

I'm trying to use a Swift class in a mostly Objective-C project. This revolves around `UIContentConfiguration` for use with `UITableViewCell`.

Here's my Swift code:

```swift
@objc class MyCellConfiguration: NSObject, UIContentConfiguration {
    let label: String

    @objc init(label: String) {
        self.label = label
    }

    func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView {
        return MyCellContent(self)
    }

    func updated(for state: UIConfigurationState) -> Self {
        return self
    }
}

class MyCellContent: UIView, UIContentView {
    // Implementation of this class is not relevant to the question
}
```

When I try to setup the cell in some Objective-C code, I get a compiler warning. If I ignore the warning, the app hangs at runtime when the code is reached.

Here's the Objective-C code:

```objective-c
#import "MyApp-Swift.h" // The bridging header is being imported

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:key forIndexPath:indexPath];

MyCellConfiguration *config = [[MyCellConfiguration alloc] initWithLabel:@"Some Label"];
cell.contentConfiguration = config; // warning here
```

The compiler warning I receive is:

> Assigning to 'id<UIContentConfiguration> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'MyCellConfiguration *__strong'

Why doesn't the compiler recognize that `MyCellConfiguration` conforms to the `UIContentConfiguration` protocol in the Objective-C code?

Swift code recognizes the conformance just fine. For example, the following compiles without issue:

```swift
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "foo")
cell.contentConfiguration = MyCellConfiguration(label: "foo")
```

I'm using Xcode 15.0 on macOS 13.6.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some observations:

- The documentation page for [`UIContentConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentconfiguration) doesn't have an Objective-C version that you can choose using the "Language: Swift" selector. The Objective-C version is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentconfiguration?language=objc).
- `UIContentConfiguration` doesn't inherit `NSObjectProtocol`, like other Objective-C protocols do, when they are imported into Swift.
- The Swift version of `UIContentConfiguration` has a `makeContentView` method that returns an intersection type, which cannot be represented in Objective-C. (The Objective-C version returns `__kindof UIView<UIContentView> *`)

These all suggest that `UIContentConfiguration` in Swift is an entirely different protocol from its Objective-C version. Just conforming to it in Swift doesn't mean you conformed to it in Objective-C.

You can also see a similar pattern in other related types like `UIContentView` and `UIConfigurationState`.

In fact, try setting `contentConfiguration` to an instance of `MyCellConfiguration` in Swift and see what happens on the Objective-C's side. Try printing out `[cell.contentConfiguration class]` in Objective-C. The output is not `MyCellConfiguration`!

All of that is to say, you have to re-implement the Objective-C version of `UIContentConfiguration` in Objective-C, or you can just add a method like this in Swift:

```
@objc
func addToCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
    cell.contentConfiguration = self
}
```

```objectivec
UITableViewCell *cell = ...;
MyCellConfiguration *config = [[MyCellConfiguration alloc] initWithLabel:@"Some Label"];
[config addToCell:cell];
```

Comment: Nice! I had noticed the weird documentation links between Swift and ObjC for `UIContentConfiguration` but I hadn't noticed the significance nor the lack of `NSObjectProtocol` conformance for the Swift version. Very interesting even if I need to study these details a bit more to fully understand. I just tried your work around and it works perfectly. And just 10 minutes ago I finished testing my reimplementation of `MyCellConfiguration` in Objective-C to avoid the issue. I should have been more patient.